# Jquery: What's better? Checking by Global Variable, or by class applied to element?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, global-variables, element

Would it be better to set a global variable, then check that?
or to set a class on an element, then check that?

what's the benefit of each?

tiny example:

```
if(something == "myGlobalVariable")
yada yada yada
```

or

```
if($('.element').hasClass('foo'))
yada yada yada
```

Comment: The two are very different things. The answer will depend heavily on what you're trying to do. So, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With global variables, you'll end up polluting the namespace, which could result in conflicts down the road. Just a bad idea in general.

There is nothing wrong with checking an element to see if it has a certain class. In fact, that is the way many plugins are written to wire by convention.